# keyup event on contenteditable div

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to format the text in an contenteditable div after `Enter` is pressed. The problem is that no keyups are being registered from any key, so this is making it impossible. Other events, such as 'click' does work, and if I change the element to 'document' (`document.addEventListener()`...) this will make it work too, but this is an extreme solution. Is there a simple solution?

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var editbox = document.getElementById("editable")
    editbox.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
        alert("this should appear");
    });
});
```

```html
<main contenteditable="true">
    <div class="box" id="editable">
        text
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use <del>`keyCode`</del> `event.key` to detect the specific key 'Enter' = <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
Use `event.target` property to detect exactly what element was typed on. The `#editable` div is within the `main` which is `contenteditable` so it can't be accessed by normal means, therefore target the `main` instead.

To test the demo:

1. Place the cursor within the blue outlined area.
2. Press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.
3. The console should log every <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key pressed.
4. Now click below the outlined area and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
5. The keyup event is ignored and there's nothing logged.

### Demo

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter' && e.target.tagName === 'MAIN') {
    console.log('ENTER');
  }
});
```

```css
#editable {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main contenteditable="true">
    <div class="box" id="editable">
      text
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: from the question text: "and if I change the element to 'document' (document.addEventListener()...) this will make it work too, but this is an extreme solution"

Comment: @qiAlex It's not an extreme solution at all. If my pattern is followed, then other elements can be included while others excluded. It's called [**Event Delegation**](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm).
 However the OP believes that registering an event to document should be avoided,
 it doesn't matter because of event bubbling document will always be part of the event chain

Comment: I know, that it is not an extreme solution, I just wanted to point that author of the question already had that solution in mind

Comment: There is very little difference between `document` and `main` on the event chain. The result still isolates `main` as `event.target` while no other element is acknowledged. I could add `e.stopPropagation()` but that might be overkill for a simple question.

Comment: keyCode is deprecated, you should be using `e.key === "Enter"`.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should listen the element with `contenteditable="true"`
2. there is special event for it called `input`.
3. you don't need `document.getElementById` at almost all cases. almost every element with `id` has it's own variable.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    let enterCount = 0;
    editable.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
        console.log ("this should appear");
        if (enterCount < e.target.querySelectorAll('br').length) {    
            console.log ('enter was pressed');
        }
        enterCount = e.target.querySelectorAll('br').length;
    });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>title</title>
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main contenteditable="true" id="editable">
            <div class="box" >
                text
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Changing the event to `input` won't tell me which key was pressed. Why do you insist on this?

Comment: Marking the contenteditable tag did solve my problem however.

Comment: I updated a code in the answer, we can simply count number of `br` childs

Comment: Listening to `keyup` is far easier, so I don't see why you insist on such a complicated solution?

Answer (score 1):

You're not attaching the listener to the right element.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var editbox = document.getElementById("elm_editable")

    editbox.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
        // and here is how to detect the enter key
        if (13 === e.keyCode) {
            alert("this should appear");
        }        
    });
});
```

```html
<main contenteditable="true" id="elm_editable">
    <div class="box" id="editable">
        text
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: keyCode is deprecated, you should be using `e.key === "Enter"`.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution. You can just detect an inputType.

```js
const divInput = document.getElementById('divInput');
const textarea = document.getElementById('inputTypePreview');

divInput.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  const t = event.inputType;
  textarea.innerHTML = `${t} \n`;
  if (t === 'insertParagraph' || t === 'insertLineBreak') 
    textarea.innerHTML = 'Enter detected \n';
 });
```

```css
#inputTypePreview {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
}
#divInput, #inputTypePreview {
  border: 1px solid #b1b0b0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="divInput" contentEditable="true"></div>
<textarea id="inputTypePreview" disabled></textarea>
```